# Are there any good tutorials on how to set up JMeter to load test a deployed ASP. NET web app?

Tags: performance, load-testing, jmeter, test-data

I'm having trouble finding a decent tutorial on how to set up JMeter to load test a deployed ASP.NET web app? Does it have to run on localhost or can it be used to test a deployed app?

I would like to test the performance of the deployed app during different times of the time and test at what times is the app most stressed or slow. Also, how long does it take to retrieve data from the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From server side perspective if you want realistic numbers your application needs to be deployed to environment close to production.

From JMeter side you need to consider the following:

1. Correlation. ASP.NET web applications use dynamic request parameters like VIEWSTATE and EVENTVALIDATION. You'll need to extract them from previous response and add to next one. JMeter provides a number of Post Processors to extract these values from response and convert them to JMeter Variables. The most commonly used are [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) and [XPath Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor)
2. Create realistic load. See [How to make JMeter behave more like a real browser](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/115022-how-to-make-jmeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser) guide on how to properly configure your JMeter instance.
3. Load patterns. Consider reasonable Thread Count and Ramp-up period (50 concurrent threads != 50 real concurrent users), use Timers to simulate think time.
4. If you need to test exact load, like X requests per second you'll need to use [Constant Throughput Timer](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-throughput-constant-timer)

Hope this helps,

D.

Comment: Thank you. I'll take a look and try to set it up. I would need to use a regular expression extractor to have JMeter log into my webpage, correct using username and password?

Comment: You need to get login page first, extract dynamic values with regular expression extractor and provide them in next request along with login and password

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure what VIEWSTATE and EVENTVALIDATION were and I read somewhere that those parameters are not needed for ASP .NET MVC 4. I'm using MVC.... Do I still have to follow the above? Sorry for the trouble.I just set up my cookie manager and I think I need to set up a way to grab the authenticity token.

Comment: Actually, I figured it out. I just need a RequestVerificationToken . The problem is now I'm getting a 500 server code status error.